# How to set a jQuery action based on two conditions

Tags: jquery

I've got a text input that is making and AJAX database call and populating an adjoining div with a set of links based on the search.  When the user leaves both the input and the div, I want to hide the div.  I'm not sure how to put a function together that checks for BOTH conditions.

Here's the HTML part.

```
<form name="searchform" id="sform" action="searchflowers.asp" method="get" style="float:left">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="search">
<input type="hidden" name="pf" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="itype" value="flower">
<input type="search" name="srch" id="thisbox" maxlength="30" id="srch" placeholder="search flowers"
    autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="Go" class="tinybutton">
<div id="suggestions"></div>
```

And the script.

```
//jquery functions
$(document).ready(function(){
//initially hide suggestions box
$("#suggestions").hide()

//retrieve matching results
$("#thisbox").keyup(function () {
    $("#suggestions").show()
    $("#suggestions").load("scripts/getlist.asp?letters=" + $("#thisbox").val())
});

    //********** this is the piece I need to fix *************
$("#sform").mouseout(function () {
    $("#suggestions").hide("slow")
});
```

});

Comment: Umm... set a variable when the user leaves the input. Check that variable when you leave the div?

Comment: When you say "the user leaves the textbox" do you mean when they unfocus it?

Comment: please please - learn how to use **angularjs** or **react** instead of using jQuery - it will make your life WAY easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that by 'user leaves both the input and the div' you mean `mouseleave` event for both right? (not `blur` event for input and `mouseleave` for div)

If your suggestions div is **inside** the form, then your code works pretty much as is (*there is no closing form tag in your example code*). If the suggestions div is meant to be outside of the form, then I would suggest putting a wrapping div around both the form and the suggestions div and hooking your `mouseleave` event to that container instead of both.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewbrown5717/gfujqbua/), that takes into account `mouseleave` event for the form (I put your div *inside* the form), and the `blur` event for the input field itself (*note that I don't have access to your 'scripts/getlist.asp', so I just put in a [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) call there instead, since your concern here seems to be the UI any ways*)